# Convergence in probability vs. convergence in quadratic mean

Tags: probability, random-variable, convergence

I read in some paper that convergence in probability implies the convergence in quadratic mean if all moments of higher order exists, but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone please provide the proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Convergence in probability does not imply convergence in quadratic mean**, did you accidentally  write the reverse statement? Some good
notes on convergence can be found [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture4.pdf). The relevant parts to your question
are reproduced below.

$X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in probability, $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$, if for every $\epsilon$,

$$
P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in quadratic mean, $X_n \xrightarrow{qm} X$, if

$$
E[(X_n - X)^2] \rightarrow 0
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$

As a counterexample to show convergence in probability does not imply convergence in quadratic mean,
take $U \sim Unif(0, 1)$ and let $X_n = \sqrt{n} I_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(U)$. Then

$$
P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = P(|\sqrt{n} I_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(U)| > \epsilon) = P(0 \leq U \leq 1/n) = 1/n \rightarrow 0
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and therefore $X_n \xrightarrow{P} 0$

but

$$
E[X_{n}^2] = n\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}dx = 1
$$

and therefore $X_n \not\xrightarrow{qm} 0$

---

With the additional constraint that $P(|X_n| < M) = 1$ for some constant $M > 0$, we do have that
convergence in probability implies convergence in quadratic mean or L2. This can
be seen as a restricted version of the following theorem from 
chapter 17 of *Convergence of Random Variables* by Jean Jacod and Philip Protter.
The relevant chapter is available [here](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiG0tTblIHUAhUl4YMKHTPEApsQFghTMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783540438717-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-88937-p2054396&usg=AFQjCNExRyuxb1iHONIVcZcIXjq40L7YQw&sig2=OfuG_nWiIHSctkors6UAsw).

> **Theorem 17.4** Suppose $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and also that $|X_{n}| \leq Y$, all $n$, and $Y \in L^p$.
>   Then $|X|$ is in $L^{p}$ and $X_{n} \xrightarrow{L^p} X$.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was not precise enough.
I'm familiar with the fact that convergence in moments implies convergence in probability but the reverse is not generally true. 

What I read in paper is that, **under assumption of bounded variables**, i.e `P(|X_n|<M) = 1` for some constant M > 0, convergence in probability does imply convergence in quadratic mean, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @mare do you want to correct the question then

Comment: @seanv507 he's asking for the proof

Comment: What does ${I_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(U)}$ mean?