# Convergence in Quadratic Mean Implies Convergence in Probability Proof Clarification

Tags: probability, convergence

Wasserman (2004) All of Statistics A Concise Course in Statistical Inference gives the following proof that *convergence in quadratic mean ($L_2$ convergence) implies convergence in probability*:

By Chebyshev's inequality, for a fixed $\epsilon$:

$$P(\vert X_n - X \vert > \epsilon) = P(\vert X_n - X \vert^2 > \epsilon^2) \leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}\vert X_n - X \vert^2}{\epsilon^2} \rightarrow 0$$

I am having trouble parsing this one-line proof to get the necessary intuition.

Is the key part of the proof equating the first two terms, so as to give that the convergence in probability can be stated as a rearrangement of $L_2$ convergence?

Is this proof then saying that the probability that the absolute deviation of $X_n$ from $X$ being greater than $\epsilon$ is *upper-bounded* by the rightmost term, which converges to zero for large $n$?

Possibly a simple question but I would appreciate expansion of the intuition and perhaps (signposting to) another proof if possible. I also checked [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280774/convergence-in-probability-vs-convergence-in-quadratic-mean), which did not provide an answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: The key to the demonstration is announced at the very beginning: Chebyshev's Inequality.  The line of mathematics explicitly relates the two forms of convergence by means of this inequality.

Comment: This is actually Markov's inequality.